# Including multiple Associations in a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I hope to explain my problem using the tables below:

```
university = University.where('class.name' => 'example', 'class.students.age' => '21').includes(:class, :student)

University
id
class.id
name

Class:
id
student.id
name
MaximumStudents

Student:
id
name
age
```

As you can see the `University` table references the `Class` table. The `Class` table references the `Student` table.

I want to get the universities that have a class called `example` and the students are aged `21`. I know it weird but it shows my problem :D

I can't get my query to get hold of the `Student`. I always get the error "Association named 'students' was not found"

It works fine if I do the following without using the `Student` table

```
university = University.where('class.name' => 'example').includes(:class)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, be advised that it's not a good idea to name a model "Class" since that's a reserved word in Ruby (for classes), which may cause trouble.

Aside from that: In the `University` model, you need to specify a relation to the `Student` model like this:

```
has_many :students, :through => :class
```

Then you can get what you want with a relation like this:

```
university = University.where('class.name' => 'example', 'students.age' => 21).includes(:class, :students)
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. The above wasn't actually my application. I shouldn't have used class.